# Journal - Automatically add cells to tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cells

I have a main view controller which loads a tableviewcontroller when you press a button.  Basically it is like a journal.  What I want to have happen is once you get to the UITableview, it has a cell with the date and the cell is highlighted.  And it continues to store each entry to the list.

I have looked at the documentation on how to add/remove cells, but I can't figure out how to do it automatically (maybe at midnight or something) and have it also enter the date...

Eventually it will load a page to enter text, but I think I know how to do that so I will do that later.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data are stored in a Core Data database, you can use the NSFetchedResultsController and implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods that tells you that requested data has changed :

```
– controllerWillChangeContent:
– controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:
– controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:
– controllerDidChangeContent:
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I will try that...are those the method signatures?

Comment: Yes, and to add an new date in your database, you could use UILocalNotification : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalNotification